# How can I edit the corner of a button in swift, in button editor?

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton

On the right panel editor, there are all the characteristics from the button. But I want to know if there is an option to round the corners of the button in this panel.

[right panel for Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXH7k.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extend UIButton and use `@IBInspectable` to be able to set the corner radius more comfortably. I added some math so that the Button can be at max a circle and always looks pleasing. `@IBDesignable` is used that the button is able to render nicely in the Storyboard.

```swift
@IBDesignable
public class CornerRadiusButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            cornerRadius = (cornerRadius > 100) ? 100 : cornerRadius
            let max = self.bounds.size.width * 0.5
            self.layer.cornerRadius = max * cornerRadius/100
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of iOS a button just shows the text.

It doesn't pay attention to the corner radius. If you set the background color to something other than transparent then it gets filled with that color.

If you want a colored rounded rectangle, set the background color, and go to the identity inspector and add an entry under "user defined runtime attributes" with a key of "layer.cornerRadius" and a number value of 5.